# Deploying Devart EF Odata app to a Server - cannot find Framework Data Provider

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, odata, devart

I followed the simple tutorial @ http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/Tutorial_EF.html 
(Which works perfectly, btw) combined with http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx for the OData part and now I need to deploy it to a server.

The problem I am having is that in step 4 of the devart tutorial, I chose a "Data Connection" to my database. Everything works fine on my dev box, but when I published the EF project, there was no reference to the DevArt dlls in the project. So, none were moved to the server.

And, of course this is producing a 'Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.'.

I tried just copying the dlls into the bin directory and I installed the devart product on the server.  Neither worked.

I am used to ASP.Net applications that reference the needed Data dlls. What do I need to do to get my EF Odata service running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following page will explain how to deploy your EF devart project:

[DevArt - Deployment](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Deployment.html)